# Energy-Based Modeling vs Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am doing some research on machine learning algorithms in the context of a seminar, which focuses on Energy-Based Modeling vs Deep Learning specifically in working with images Modeling. Now I know these are broad topics, but I was wondering what some specific similarities and differences are. I have read countless papers that say "EBMs have properties that make them better than DL in certain tasks" but I haven't really found a comprehensive motivation

- What is the problem that EBM is solving compared to DL?
- Why are we doing this?

I hope this is the right site for this question, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms brought me here.

Thanks in advance